# How to insert into middle of line in file in Python

Tags: python, file

I have the following code in a file "code.s":

```
   movi $1,10
beginning: jeq $1, $0,done
   addi $1, $1,-1
   j beginning
done: halt
```

I want to insert a newline character '\n' directly after each ":" character in the file. How would I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Hmm… so you are looking for the `sed` equivalent in Python?

Comment: Feel free to share how you have tried approaching this problem. Also include the size of the file, this is important to know since reading a huge file into memory wouldn't be a good idea, while if the file is always 5 lines long, this approach is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your file, you can try reading it into memory as a string.

Then using the `yourstring.replace(target, replacement)` function, replace each `":"` with `":\n"`.

Write this data back to your file:

```
with open("code.s", "w") as the_file:
    # This will delete the contents of the file, make a backup
    the_file.write(yourstring)
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about writing it back to the file?

Comment: @anti4r, I have updated the answer with info on writing

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\LAVANYA\OneDrive\Documents\am3') 
file=open('am2.txt','r')
doc=file.readlines()
a=[]
for i in doc:
    a.append(i.replace(":",":\n"))
file=open('am2.txt','w')
file.writelines(a)
file.close()
```